# Sum of infinite powers

Tags: calculus, number-theory

I know that the sum $1+x+x^2+...+x^n$ is  $\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}$ but when $n \to \infty$ the sum is $1/(1-x)$ when $ - 1 < x <1$. I can derive the former but not the latter.

How is this the case? How do you prove this? If I use the formula above, replacing $n $ with infinity seems to make the whole thing infinity.

Comment: Think about how $x^n$ behaves for large $n$ when $-1<x<1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{a_0r^{n-1}} \equiv S$$
$$S = a_0r^0+a_0r^1+a_0r^2+\cdots$$
$$S = r\left(a_0r^{-1} + a_0r^{0} + a_0r^1+\cdots\right)$$
$$S = r\left(a_0r^{-1} + S\right)$$
$$S = a_0 + rS$$
$$(1-r)S = a_0$$
$$S = \frac{a_0}{(1-r)}$$
In this case, $a_0=1$ and $r=x$.
Also, if you want to see it from the general formula $$S=\frac{(1−r^n)}{1−r}$$
$$S=\frac{1}{1-r}-\frac{r^n}{1-r}$$

For $n → ∞$, the quantity $\frac{r^n}{1-r}→ 0$ for $-1.0 < (r ≠ 0) < +1.0$.

Comment: I'm starting the sum from i=0 though, not 1 (does that matter? )

Comment: I don't think $i=0$ would make sense. You started from $i=1$ only. Sorry, it is supposed to be $i$ in place of $n$ if that is what confusing you.

Answer (score 0):

So as you are aware the sum to infinity requires $|x|<1$

This then means that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x^{n+1} = 0$

In turn this means that 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}=\frac{-1}{x-1}=\frac{1}{1-x}
$$

Comment: What do we say the limit is if $x>=1$? Doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

To show that
$x^n \to 0$
as $n \to \infty$
when
$0 < x < 1$:

Since
$0 < x < 1$,
$x = \frac1{1+a}
$,
where
$a
=\frac1{x}-1
> 0
$.

By Bernoulli's inequality,
$(1+a)^n
\ge 1+na
> na
$.

Therefore
$x^n
=\frac1{(1+a)^n}
< \frac1{na}
= \frac1{n(1/x-1)}
\to 0
$
as
$n \to \infty$.

Note:
Nothing here is original.